# Convert iso xsl to svrl xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know if this is true. i have an iso xsl file,
I want to convert it to svrl xsl file. because I can do the schematron check with svrl xsl file.

I'm adding sample code snippets in the iso xsl and svrl xsl files I mentioned
What kind of a solution should I follow? Thanks

**Simple iso xsl;**

```
 <xsl:template match="sh:StandardBusinessDocument" priority="1000" mode="M23">
        <!--ASSERT -->
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"/>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
               <xsl:text>sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader is required.</xsl:text>
            </xsl:message>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <!--ASSERT -->
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="ef:Package"/>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
               <xsl:text>ef:Package is required.</xsl:text>
            </xsl:message>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <!--ASSERT -->
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains(@xsi:schemaLocation,'PackageProxy_1_2.xsd')"/>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
               <xsl:text>sh:StandardBusinessDocument xsi:schemaLocation must be 'PackageProxy_1_2.xsd'</xsl:text>
            </xsl:message>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <!--ASSERT -->
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not(name()= 'Invoice') or string-length(normalize-space(string(namespace::xsi))) != 0"/>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
               <xsl:text>Invoice element and xmlns: xsi attribute with no null values. </xsl:text>
            </xsl:message>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="M23"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

**Simple svrl xsl;**

```
     <xsl:template match="sh:StandardBusinessDocument" mode="M20" priority="1000">
    <svrl:fired-rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocument" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"/>
    <!--ASSERT -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <svrl:failed-assert test="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">
          <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="schematron-select-full-path" select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <svrl:text>sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader is required.</svrl:text>
        </svrl:failed-assert>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--ASSERT -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="ef:Package"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <svrl:failed-assert test="ef:Package" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">
          <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="schematron-select-full-path" select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <svrl:text>ef:Package is required.</svrl:text>
        </svrl:failed-assert>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--ASSERT -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(@xsi:schemaLocation,'PackageProxy_1_2.xsd')"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <svrl:failed-assert test="contains(@xsi:schemaLocation,'PackageProxy_1_2.xsd')" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">
          <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="schematron-select-full-path" select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <svrl:text>sh:StandardBusinessDocument xsi:schemaLocation must be 'PackageProxy_1_2.xsd'</svrl:text>
        </svrl:failed-assert>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="M20" select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put your schematron schema through a different schematron engine?